# Add git commit SHA to iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, git

I want to show the current git SHA of when my project was built in my App. What is a good way of doing this in an iOS project with minimal effort?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **Version 2.17. Build a85b242.**

If you want to add a pretty versioning like this above, just follow these steps:

1. Open `Build Phases` in **Xcode**
2. Press `Add Build Phase`
3. Press `Add Run Script Build Phase`. You can find this in the top menu **Editor**. Drag script-line to the position after `Target Dependencies`.
4. Set **Shell** line to `/bin/sh`
5. Set the script below to the **Script field**. Don't forget to change **Sources** to your path-to-file, where `GitVersion.h` should be. For example:

   ```
   version=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c 1-7)
   curdate=$(date +"%d.%m.%y")

   filesource="//\n//  GitVersion.h\n//\n//  Created by sig on $curdate.\n//\n\n#ifndef GitVersion_h\n#define GitVersion_h\n\n#define GIT_SHA_VERSION @\"$version\"\n\n#endif"

   cd ${SOURCE_ROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}
   echo -e "$filesource" > Sources/GitVersion.h

   touch Sources/GitVersion.h
   ```
6. Import `GitVersion.h` file into **Xcode** project
7. Paste these lines:

   ```
   NSDictionary *info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
   NSString *version = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
   NSString *app_version = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@. Build %@.", version, GIT_SHA_VERSION];

   NSLog(@"app_version : %@", app_version);
   ```

> Fully documented answer with images and described advantages could be found [here](https://github.com/siggb/GitVersioningOnXCode).

Comment: And then you commit this file every time?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in Schemes. Open your scheme (edit), expand Build in your scheme, click on Pre-Actions, click on + button, select New Run Script Action and write some script which gets SHA and modifies some header file where you can put SHA (easiest way is `#define GIT_SHA @"..."`) and use `GIT_SHA` in your app in a place where you can display it.

Comment: The “write some script” part is the non-trivial part.  Your answer is basically _“how do I make Xcode do something at compile time”_ when the question was essentially _“how do I make Xcode at compile time get the current Git SHA and make it accessible to Objective-C/Swift code”_.

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer, but for those who needs to get `Git Commit SHA`, here is an easy solution:

Select the Target that you want to get the `Git Commit SHA` for. Then Go to the `Build Phase`.

1- Create a New Run Scrip Phase by pressing the + button and Add the following script:

```
git_version=$(git log -1 --format="%h")


info_plist="${SRCROOT}/{THE_PATH_TO_PLIST_FILE}/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :GIT_VERSION '${git_version}'" "${info_plist}"
```

remember to replace `{THE_PATH_TO_PLIST_FILE}` with the real path to your plist file.

3- Now Go to the `Info.plist` for the same Target and add a new property named: `GIT_VERSION`. The script will set the GitVersion to this property.

4- Read the `GIT_VERSION` from `Info.plist` in code.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift**

[Git log format link](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

**Other Swift Flags**
[image]

**Run Script**

```
version=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c 1-10)
commitDate=$(git log -n 1 HEAD --pretty=format:"%h - %cd" | cut -c 12-)

filesource="//\n//  GitVersion.swift\n//\n//  Commit Date:$commitDate\n//\n\n#if DEBUG\nlet gitVersion = \"$version\"\n#endif"
cd ${SOURCE_ROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}

echo -e "$filesource" > GitVersion.swift

touch GitVersion.swift
```

**GitVersion.swift**

```
//
//  GitVersion.swift
//
//  Commit Date: Tue Jun 19 11:09:55 2018 +0900
//

#if DEBUG
let gitVersion = "2fd2f0315d"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift Projects**

Source: https://github.com/ankushkushwaha/AppVersionInXcode

1. Add build script Run Script

   #/bin/sh

   version=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c 1-7)

   fileContent="// DO NOT EDIT,
   // IT IS A MACHINE GENERATED FILE

   //  AppInfo.swift
   //
   import Foundation
   class AppInfo {
       let version: String
       let build: String
       let gitCommitSHA: String = \"$version\"
       init?() {
           guard let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[\"CFBundleShortVersionString\"] as? String,
               let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[\"CFBundleVersion\"] as? String else {
                   return nil
               }
           self.version = version
           self.build = build
       }
   }"
   echo "$fileContent" > AppInfo.swift
2. Move/Drag the run script above the 'compile sources'
3. Now Build your project, It will create a file AppInfo.swift in project's root folder
4. Drag an drop AppInfo.swift file into your Xcode project navigator.
5. Use as below

   guard let info = AppInfo() else {
       return
   }
   let infoText = "AppVersion: (info.version) \nBuild: (info.build) \nGit hash: (info.gitCommitSHA)"
   print(infoText)

Answer (score 0):

This link worked for my case, but I would just add that it is a nice thing to add the project path and the folder where this auto generated class is put. So in my case it is:

```
echo "$fileContent" > ${SRCROOT}/MyProject/Models/AppInfo.swift
```

Here is a nice post about relative paths:

[Relative paths on Xcode scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824498/relative-paths-on-xcode-scripts)