# Relative paths on Xcode scripts

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm experimenting running scripts with Xcode and have got a couple of questions:

1) Xcode says to drag n drop the script into the run script section but that creates an absolute path: /Users/Me/Desktop/Project/etc. which is obviously no use if somebody else or a CI machine checks out the code. How to specify a relative path?

2) There's a permission denied error during the build when the script gets executed.

(I'm using scripts off here to experiment with https://gist.github.com/sekati/3172554)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) In an Xcode project of mine, I have the following script that generates the source code documentation. As you can see each line of the script uses a relative path. I don't even need to use `${SRCROOT}`.

```
# change directory because Doxyfile is configured with a relative input path ".."
cd doxygen

# clean the directory
rm -rf html

# generate docs
/opt/local/bin/doxygen Doxyfile

# open the html documentation
open html/index.html
```

2) The reason for the "permission denied" error may be that you have not set the executable bit on the script. On the console, type this command to set the executable bit, then try again to run the script.

```
chmod +x /path/to/xcode-build-bump.sh
```

Answer (score 12):

"$[SRCROOT](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38)" gives the project folder:

i.e: *Users/yourUserName/MyProject*

but if you have a workspace folder with multiple projects inside:
i.e: *Users/yourUserName/MyWorkspace/MyProject*

And you need just the workspace folder, **use 2 dots**:

*"**..**/SomeFodler"*
While someFolder will be created in the workspace folder.

Simple as that.

Answer (score 11):

1) Edit your script with the following:

- Root of the project: `${SRCROOT}`
- Root of the build: `${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}`

2) Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>, click `Build` and read the error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what you mean by click Build in addition to starting a build using the Apple-B key sequence. The error message is "....xcode-build-bump.sh: Permission denied"

Comment: When you click Build in the Log Navigator (⌘+8), the result of running the script appears on the right, and you can read the output to debug it as you would with a bash script.